# Autoprinting an iText-generated PDF

Tags: java, itext

Is there a way to send a newly iText-generated PDF directly to the printer ? Preferably in the same method that is used to generate it and save it to disc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and this works fine after you have saved the file in the disk.

```
 import com.lowagie.tools.Executable;

try{
 Executable ex = new Executable();
 ex.openDocument(fileName);
 ex.printDocument(fileName);
 }catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

For more info, see this [Daniweb forum conversation](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/150116).